# How do I change POPUP Text of Menu without ID

Tags: visual-studio-2008, menu, mfc, popup

For many language, I must dynamic change POPUP Text of Menu,

but it is no ID to control this text, as follow code reference resource

```
IDR_MENU_MAIN MENU 
BEGIN
    POPUP "File(&F)" // I want to change this
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "Open(&O)",                    ID_CURVE_FILE_NEW
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "Recent File",                 ID_FILE_MRU_FILE1, GRAYED
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "E&xit",                       ID_APP_EXIT
END
POPUP "Language(&L)"   // I want to change this
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "Traditional Chinese",         ID_LANGUAGE_CHT
    MENUITEM "Simplified Chinese",          ID_LANGUAGE_CHS
    MENUITEM "English",                     ID_LANGUAGE_ENG
    MENUITEM "Russian",                     ID_LANGUAGE_RUS
    MENUITEM "Korean",                      ID_LANGUAGE_KOR
    MENUITEM "Japanese",                    ID_LANGUAGE_JPN
END
POPUP "Help(&H)"    // I want to change this
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "", ID_APP_ABOUT
END
END
```

thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I response my question, change the code

```
CMenu* pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(hMenu);
```

to

```
CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
```

It will work! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Following is some code to `TRACE` and modify the popup-menu strings (`hMenu` is the handle to the main menu);  if your application uses the "new style" menu bar `CMFCMenuBar`, you will need to call `m_wndMenuBar.GetHMenu()` and `m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(hMenu, TRUE, TRUE);` before and afterwards respectively:

```
CMenu* pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(hMenu);
int i, nCou = pMenu->GetMenuItemCount();
UINT uID;
CString ss;
for (i = 0; i < nCou; i++)
{   uID = pMenu->GetMenuItemID(i);
    if (uID == 0) // separator
    {   TRACE(_T("----------------------\n"));
        continue;
    }
    pMenu->GetMenuString(i, ss, MF_BYPOSITION);
    if (uID == (UINT)-1)
    {   TRACE(_T("Popup '%s' "), ss);
        ss += _T("-Modified");
        pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION, 0, ss);
        TRACE(_T("modified to '%s' "), ss);
    }
    else
        TRACE(_T("Item  '%s', ID=%d "), ss, uID);
    TRACE(_T("\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But it does'nt work, In output window show following message, but it not change of menu popup text.

------------------------------------------
Popup 'File(&F)' modified to 'File(&F)-Modified' 
Popup 'Set(&S)' modified to 'Set(&S)-Modified' 
Popup 'Language(&L)' modified to 'Language(&L)-Modified' 
Popup 'Help(&H)' modified to 'Help(&H)-Modified' 
------------------------------------------

I think maybe this -> "pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION, 0, ss);"
Not work

Comment: How is your menu hosted? [in a dialog or a MFC Document/View structure? with a CToolbar or a CMFCToolbar?] how do you get hold of `hMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '**setlocale**'.
For example:
setlocale( LC_ALL, "Traditional Chinese" ); 
setlocale( LC_ALL, "Simplified Chinese" );
..
..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It's maybe not adapter for me, because I have many text to change

Comment: @user1753112 Sorry for not being helpful :/

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky.

What I have done is to have an enumeration that matches the top-level elements of the menubar and then reference them by position.

Then instead of using MF_BYCOMMAND to update them you must use MF_BYPOSITION.

Comment: Excuse me, I an new hand of MFC, can you create a example for me about using MF_BYCOMMAND

Answer (score -1):

My menu is dialog and with CToolbar