# How do I dynamic change MENU text which without ID

Tags: visual-studio-2008, menu, mfc, dialog, popup

I have try follow code to change the menu text, In command window show the correct activity, change the menu text, but the UI no change.

Another, my menu is on dialog, fill it in menu field of dialog parameter

the old question is

[How do I change POPUP Text of Menu without ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039268/how-do-i-change-popup-text-of-menu-without-id)

someone help me !

```
HMENU hMenu;
hMenu=LoadMenu(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU));
CMenu* pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(hMenu);
int i, nCou = pMenu->GetMenuItemCount();
UINT uID;
CString ss;
for (i = 0; i < nCou; i++)
{   
    uID = pMenu->GetMenuItemID(i);
    if (uID == 0) // separator
    {   
        TRACE(_T("----------------------\n"));
        continue;
    }
    pMenu->GetMenuString(i, ss, MF_BYPOSITION);
    if (uID == (UINT)-1)
    {   
        TRACE(_T("Popup '%s' "), ss);
        ss += _T("-Modified");
        //pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_STRING|MF_ENABLED, 0, ss);
        //pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_STRING|MF_ENABLED, i, ss);
        //pMenu->ModifyMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_STRING|MF_ENABLED, i, ss);
        //pMenu->ModifyMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_STRING|MF_ENABLED, 0, ss);
        //pMenu->ModifyMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_STRING|MF_ENABLED|MF_CHANGE, 0, ss);
        //pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION, 0, ss);
        pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_CHANGE, 0, ss);
        TRACE(_T("modified to '%s' "), ss);
    }
    else
        TRACE(_T("Item  '%s', ID=%d "), ss, uID);

    TRACE(_T("\n"));
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you assign this menu to the frame/dialog? If not you change has no effect...

Comment: My menu is on dialog, No change of menu text which without id

Comment: But you have a loop and modify with MF_BYPOSITION. The code you posted should work WHEN you use this menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I response my question, change the code

```
CMenu* pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(hMenu);
```

to

```
CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
```

It will work! thanks a lot!

Comment: Another, the menu can't redraw, must use setmenu() to reflash.