# In MDI mode, Dynamic change menu caption which without ID

Tags: menu, mfc, trace, mdi

The old question, is for menu on dialog, to change the menu caption which no id
[How do I dynamic change MENU text which without ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186934/how-do-i-dynamic-change-menu-text-which-without-id)
the code is

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//CMenu* pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(GetSkinMenu(m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd))->GetSubMenu(1);
HMENU hMenu;
hMenu=LoadMenu(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU_S8521));
//CMenu* pMenu = CMenu::FromHandle(hMenu);
CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
int i, nCou = pMenu->GetMenuItemCount();
UINT uID;
CString strMenu;
for (i = 0; i < nCou; i++)
{   
    uID = pMenu->GetMenuItemID(i);

    if (uID == 0) // separator
    {   
        //TRACE(_T("----------------------\n"));
        continue;
    }
    //pMenu->GetMenuString(i, ss, MF_BYPOSITION);
    if (uID == (UINT)-1)
    {   
        //TRACE(_T("Popup '%s' "), ss);

        if(i == 0)
        {
            strMenu = theApp.mLang.structMenuLang.strMenuFile;
        }

        if(i == 1)
        {
            strMenu = theApp.mLang.structMenuLang.strMenuSet;
        }

        if(i == 2)
        {
            strMenu = theApp.mLang.structMenuLang.strMenuLanguage;
        }

        if(i == 3)
        {
            strMenu = theApp.mLang.structMenuLang.strMenuHelp;
        }

        pMenu->ModifyMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION|MF_STRING|MF_ENABLED, 0, strMenu);
        //TRACE(_T("modified to '%s' "), ss);
    }
    //else
    //  TRACE(_T("Item  '%s', ID=%d "), ss, uID);

    //TRACE(_T("\n"));
}
//Invalidate(true);
//UpdateWindow();
this->SetMenu(pMenu);
```

Now I want to change the MID menu caption which also no id,

the keyword code is

```
this->SetMenu(pMenu);
```

then the menu will reflash. My question is On MDI Menu, how do I reflash the menu caption
, In out command window i find the TRACE message is right, but the UI no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I get method to solve it using

```
CMenu menu;
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_MAIN);
AfxGetMainWnd()->SetMenu(pMenu);
AfxGetMainWnd()->DrawMenuBar();
pMenu->Detach();
```